# How to access JavaScript execution trace at runtime in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, javascript-engine

I want to know how to access JavaScript execution trace at runtime. I saw Firebug can do something like this:

[image]

Refer to the image above, all the line numbers executed are highlighted in green. They are achieved at runtime. I guess there must be some way to access those info from the JavaScript engine used by the browser.

Say now I want to build a firebug plugin to access those info and examine all the variables in each executed line at the runtime, how should I start?

Comment: This is not the case in the firebug. It shows green lines only on the lines which has some execution in it (hence excluding braces `{}`). The lines may not get executed. It doesn't show execution trace. Try putting `if(){} else{}` into the code and see it will show both blocks on code with green lines

Comment: @tanmaykhandelwal Thanks, but it is not true. Please refer to my updated screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of firebug do you have. I have 1.11.2 which also shows green line number at the line `if(false){`. Can you add an executable line in the false condition of if statement as well? Like this:
`if(false){var a = '1';} else {var b = '2';}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you asked the [same question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/firebug/MQJCrYSwT9k) in the Firebug forum.

To duplicate Honza's answer:

> Firebug is currently using JSD (jsdIDebuggerService) to figure out,
>   which line is executable. However, the plan is to switch to JSD2 (work
>   in progress) https://wiki.mozilla.org/Debugger
>
> You should also base your extension on JSD2
>
> Look for `getLineOffsets(line)` and `getOffsetLine(offset)` in the
>   Debugger document. I didn't test it, but I think that if getLineOffset
>   returns null, the line is not executable.

Sebastian